# WTForms IntegerField doesn't work properly with NumberRange as validator

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a problem with a validator. When I'm trying to submit a form with a IntegerField 0 doesn't work,flask yelling `This field is requiered`.
The form:

```
class Update_vars(FlaskForm):
    start_date = DateField('Start date',validators = [DataRequired()])
    end_date = DateField('End date',validators = [DataRequired()])
    vals_allwd = IntegerField('Values allowed',validators=[DataRequired(),NumberRange(0,10)])
```

If you encountered this problem and know how to fix it, please let me know.
Thanks. Have a great day!

**EDIT**: I'm thinking that 0 is read as `False` for `DataRequired()`.

Comment: In fact, the error message depends on the `DataRequired` validator. If you use [`InputRequired`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.InputRequired) instead, the problem should not arise.

Comment: @Detlef that seems to fix my issue. thanks!